# Prevent MySQL login with no user or password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed MySQL like so:

```sh
sudo apt install mysql-server -y && mysql_secure_installation;
```

and did the following

```sql
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However, I can still access MySQL with:

```
sudo mysql
```

I don't understand how it has access with no user or password... How do I prevent this?

Comment: STOP using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` with `ALTER USER`/ `CREATE USER` commands. Its really not needed and never where. Edit question with `SHOW CREATE USER` from the `sudo mysql` prompt? Also what version (`SELECT VERSION()`?

Comment: Use mysqladmin password

Answer (score 0):

when you run `sudo mysql` command its authenticated with auth socket, you can check authentication used using query below.

```
mysql> SELECT plugin from mysql.user where User='root';
```

if you wnat disable that and using native authentication, run this query.

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', authentication_string = PASSWORD('changeme') WHERE User = 'root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and if you need more information, you can read [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) about auth socket.